# New versions of an app and its Push Notifications

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

Im about to upload my app but the uploader is complaining about the bundle version, it says it should be a higher version than the previous one.

The problem is that my app uses Push Notifications, so when I created the App Id to have notifications I input the bundle version of my app, from there I created the Distribution profiles and then to xcode to sign them. Also the .p12 is stored in my server so that Apple verifies my notifications are ok.
So if I get it right, each time I make an update of my app I have to re-do this whole process, and also keeping old .p12 so that users with old versions of my app will still get notifications?
Is this right?

All this bureaurazy is making me nuts, maybe Im not understanding it well. So please give me a hand.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your info.plist check that the bundle version is equal to the version of the new app in iTunes Connect

Comment: it is the same, and when I upload it shows an error, it says "The key CFBundleVersion in the info.plist file must contain a higher version than that the previously uploaded version"

Comment: Check twice, in info.plist there is a "Bundle versions string, short" and a "Bundle version".

Comment: It was complaining about my Bundle Version not my Bundle Identifier!, lack of sleep!